# Does any body know the cost of switching rim brakes to disc brakes?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I am wondering how much it would cost to upgrade from rim to disc

Comment: Probably less than a new bike, more than selling the existing bike and buying a used one of similar spec. In terms of function, good rim brakes (especially Parallelogram V brakes) with well adjusted high quality pads gets you to about 90+% performance of a mid range disc.

Comment: There's no way to tell.  Some bikes you could do it for under $100 (for cheap components), others would cost hundreds, if they're doable at all.

Comment: We need a lot more information to give a relevant answer.  Do you own the bike already?  Does it have forks/frame  with disk caliper mounts (maybe)?  Does your wheel have a disk-compatible hub (unlikely)?

Comment: edit rejected - its still way too broad even if you specify what kind of rim brakes.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the bike.

The first question is if its possible to mount disc brakes to the frame+fork. If the frame isn't ready, this could mean a new fork, the use of an adapter like BrakeTherapy, or hiring a framebuilder to retrofit the bike for disc brakes somehow.

If the frame+fork is ready, then you have to worry about the wheels. If the hubs aren't disc hubs, you'll need to either rebuild the wheels with disc hubs or buy new wheels (the latter being the more likely option).

Then, assuming you have a frame+fork and wheels which are disc ready, you have to buy the braking system -- the brake calipers, rotors, cabling/hoses and levers (should you need new ones). Note that if you have combined brake+shift levers, you may need to get new shifters and brake levers depending on the selected brakes (as pointed out by mattnz in the comments).

In many cases, this can be prohibitively expensive or economically unreasonable versus just buying a bike which is disc ready.

Comment: If current brake lever/shifter is a combined unit, and you don't get compatible pull cable brakes, you will need new shifters.

Comment: You could conceivably dremel away the brake portion of the levers and attach the shifters only. Or something.

Comment: It's rare for a frame/fork top be disc ready without having discs fitted.  My hybrid has a disc-ready *frame* because the next model up had discs and used the same frame, but it would need new forks.  If you're making mass-market bikes, discs forks will always be more expensive than non-disc: more metal, more machining operations.  So you wouldn't fit them and not use them.

Comment: @ChrisH - well, there was a period when a lot models were transitioning between rim brakes and discs when the "disc ready"-ness was reasonably common (as your hybrid fits in, most likely).